# Swift 4 Codable decode URL from String

Tags: ios, swift

I am currently trying to decode Property list using `PropertyListEncoder` and Swift 4 `Codable` protocol.

I tried some basic types (Strings, Ints, ..) and these all works just fine, but I am not able decode URL. I read multiple articles on this topic and I am pretty sure this should just work. However, the following example fails the decoding with this error:

```
Expected to decode Dictionary<String, Any> but found a string/data instead.
```

I think this works correctly with `.json` files and I didn't find any informations about different support for codable types in `JSONDecoder` and `PropertyListDecoder`. Could this be caused by parser incompatibility?

I am using Xcode 9.1 and Swift 4.0.2.

Sample `.plist`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>web</key>
        <string>https://link.to</string>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

Sample Swift code:

```swift
struct Info: Codable {
   let web: URL
}

func loadInfo() {
    let propertiesDecoder = PropertyListDecoder()
    let data = try! Data(contentsOf:
        Bundle.main.url(forResource: "web", withExtension: "plist")!)

    try! propertiesDecoder.decode(Info.self, from: data)
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can store URLs in Property Lists, and use the default Decodable implementation.

Based on the implementation of the [Decodable protocol init](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/6f19f4d1c3a57e14afc7e8d0d6d56a612080e4cf/stdlib/public/SDK/Foundation/URL.swift#L1216) in the Swift standard library, you must store the URL as a dictionary in the Plist, in a key called "relative". Optionally, you can also include a nested URL dictionary named "base" in the dictionary. These two values will get passed to the `URL(string: relative, relativeTo: base)` constructor during decoding.

For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>apiHost</key>
        <dict>
            <key>relative</key>
            <string>https://example.com/api/v0</string>
        </dict>
        <key>otherKey</key>
        <string>SomeValue</string>
       </dict>
 </array>
 </plist>
```

This Plist will decode using the following:

```
struct PlistItem: Codable {
    let apiHost: URL
    let otherKey: String
}
guard let filePath = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Data", withExtension: "plist") else { return }
do {
    let data = try Data(contentsOf: filePath)
    let decoder = PropertyListDecoder()
    let values = try decoder.decode([PlistItem].self, data)
}
catch { }
```

Comment: Thanks for the url. I noticed they moved the SDK out to another repo https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/main/Sources/Foundation/URL.swift#L1029

Answer (score 2):

As I can see the key `web` has a value of type `String` so we need to keep a matching type

But to get the string as a `URL` then we need to add a computed variable and maybe to optimize it a little bit we can make the variable lazy i.e it will be calculated once when it's needed

The edited strut would look like this:

```
struct Info: Codable {
    let web: String

    lazy var url: URL? = { return URL(string: web) }()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the URL in your JSON is properly formatted, you should be able to manually decode from String to URL like this with Swift 5:

```
let json = """
    {
        "name": "Dissent",
        "url": "https://www.dissentmagazine.org"
    }
"""

func hexAConversion(from hex: String)->Int {
    return Int(Int32(bitPattern: (UInt32(hex, radix: 16)!)))
}

let data = json.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!

let decoder = JSONDecoder()

struct CodeMe: Decodable {
  var name: String
  var url: URL?
    
  enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case name, url
  }
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
        self.url = URL(string: try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .url))
    }
  }

let codeMe = try! decoder.decode(CodeMe.self, from: data)

print(codeMe.url) // prints: Optional(https://www.dissentmagazine.org)
```

Using a similar technique you could also have a custom encoding strategy to make your object conform to Codable instead of Decodable. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/65315622/713077 for more details.